# Iterate through dynamic array and re-use values in next request

Tags: karate, jsonpath

I would like to do the following:

1. Send a request to a server and retrieve details of animals available in a petstore.

**post** /getAnimalStatus response:

```
    "animals": [
        {
            "animalId": "567839",
            "gender": "Female",
            "age": 2,
            "isEligibleAsPet": true,
            "animalStatus": "AVAILABLE"
        },
        {
            "animalId": "648562",
            "gender": "Male",
            "age": 3,
            "isEligibleAsPet": true,
            "animalStatus": "AVAILABLE"
        },
        {
            "animalId": "965895",
            "gender": "Female",
            "age": 5,
            "isEligibleAsPet": false,
            "animalStatus": "UNAVAILABLE"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would then like to:

2. Search for all animals which are `UNAVAILABLE` in the response and store the array value in a variable.
3. Send a request to a server to update **all** unavailable animals' statuses to 'AVAILABLE'
4. This request will be formatted as below where we are using the array value from the response above in the `animal` object below.:

put /updateAnimals

```
    "animal": {
        "animalId": "965895",
        "gender": "Female",
        "age": 5,
        "isEligibleAsPet": false,
        "animalStatus": "UNAVAILABLE"
    },
    "updateStatus": "AVAILABLE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2. use JsonPath (or `karate.filter()`) to do it: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters
3. use a second feature file and `call` to iterate: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

Also look at this answer for ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60358697/143475

Please ask a more specific question to get a more specific answer.